# What is the best way in Lightening Salesforce to manage the text content of the site from a single file

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning

Trying to separate the content of the page into a single file, so whenever a text on site changes, I dont have to go to every page and change the text but change it from the file and it will reflect on all pages, smth that can be useful for multi language support!

I currently dont have any code written as this is not as important as first thinking of organizing the structure for it, like, what format the text content would be, where to put the file, how to better extract etc.

Comment: Can you please give some more details? What pages are you referring to? Community, Page Layout or Lightning App? And what text are you referring to? Labels, help text, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to just use custom settings and reference the custom settings on your pages instead of hardcoding the values?